# Is it possible to refresh expired url (for file on aws bucket)

Tags: url, amazon-s3

I have file on aws bucket. This file should be accessable on url, but this particular url has expired (expiration time two weeks), and now i need somehome make this file accesible on url.

I am receiving the following error message when trying to access the URL:

```
this XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below "
```

and shows xml with error code

`AccessDenied` and message `Request has expired`

Comment: Are you getting any particular error message from AWS upon trying to use the expired url?

Comment: "this XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below " and shows xml whith error code "AccessDenied" and message "Request has expired"

Comment: Do you generate the pre-signed URLs yourself or do you just get them from somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strictly impossible to extend the lifetime of an S3 pre-signed URL beyond its original expiration timestamp.

A review of the logic behind the two possible signing algorithms, both [Signature Version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/auth-request-sig-v2.html) (deprecated, this can be identified by the presence of `AWSAccessKeyId` in the query string) and [Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) (identified by `X-Amz-Credential` in the query string), makes it apparent why this is true -- the service doesn't retain a copy of the signed URL, and the expiration parameter is one of the inputs to the HMAC-SHA signing process, so it is effectively immune to tampering.

You need to generate or obtain a new pre-signed URL.

---

*Bonus trivia: when a pre-signed URL is expired, S3 doesn't even bother validating whether the signature is correct or the credentials used to generate it are valid -- the request is rejected immediately.*